# Finding a variable count given another variable in Python

Tags: python

Using Python 3

I am trying to pull the total count for each group:
1 - control and convert
2 - treatment and convert

```
control = df2[df2.group == 'control']
treatment = df2[df2.group == 'treatment']

old = df2[df2.landing_page == 'old']
new = df2[df2.landing_page == 'convert']
```

I've tried a couple different things:
    control.user_id.count() + convert.user_id.count()
But this just adds both groups up.

I also tried a groupby but I can't get the syntax to work.

```
df2.groupby(df2[df2.group =='control', 
'old']).landing_page().reset_index(name='Count')
```

What is the best way to pull a group given the presence in another group?

Comment: Title should be changed

Comment: yes i can pull the individual totals, I'm just not sure how to put them together.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? can you give us some data? for example, are you trying to find number of rows which satisfy a certain condition?

Comment: We have those in the control group and those in the treatment group.  I want to find out how many who were in the control group are also in the convert group, for example.

A row of data would read like:
id,control,convert
 OR id,control,old
 OR id,treatment,convert
etc

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

Two arrays:

`a = [(1,2.1232),(3,5)]
b = [(1,2.1232),(5,5)]`

List comprehension for finding how many of a are in b:

`sum([x in a for x in b])`

Returns: 1

Comment: True statements = 1 so the sum function will add up every time an a[i] is in b.